# Whole word replacements using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list of original words and replace with words which I want to replace occurrence of the original words in some sentences to the replace words.

For example my list:

```
theabove      the above
myaddress     my address
```

So the sentence "This is theabove." will become "This is the above."

I am using Regular Expression in VB like this:

```
Dim strPattern As String
Dim regex As New RegExp

regex.Global = True

If Not IsEmpty(myReplacementList) Then
  For intRow = 0 To UBound(myReplacementList, 2)
       strReplaceWith = IIf(IsNull(myReplacementList(COL_REPLACEMENTWORD, intRow)), " ", varReplacements(COL_REPLACEMENTWORD, intRow))
       strPattern = "\b" & myReplacementList(COL_ORIGINALWORD, intRow) & "\b"
       regex.Pattern = strPattern

       TextToCleanUp = regex.Replace(TextToReplace, strReplaceWith)
  Next
End If
```

I loop all entries in my list myReplacementList against the text TextToReplace I want to process, and the replacement have to be whole word so I used the "\b" token around the original word.

It works well but I have a problem when the original words contain some special characters for example

```
overla)   overlay
```

I try to escape the ) in the pattern but it does not work:

```
\boverla\)\\b
```

I can't replace the sentence "This word is overla) with that word." to "This word is overlay with that word."

Not sure what is missing? Is regular expression the way to the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use string.replace().
That way you don't have to escape special chars .. only these: ""!
See here for examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-vbnet

Regex is good if your looking for patterns. Or renaming your mp3 collection ;-) and much, much more. But in your case, I'd use string.replace().

Comment: Thanks @gilu, my problem with string.replace is that, it does not handle whole word replacement easily. 

For example if I were to replace "carr" with "car", my sentence "This is my carr and the cash I carried." would become "This is my car and the cash I caried."

Comment: I see, you're right!!
This is tricky!
What you could do is, remove all the +"*ç%&/() from your string (string.replace()) and then use your regex to find those words.

Microsoft has an article about regex.escape
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx
That might help too.